# Swift NSPredicate String Variable doesn't Return Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

When using NSPredicate, why does a hard coded string work but a string variable does not work?

For example:

**This code returns results:**

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "level_id", "A2768F75-2293-4286-9ERA-D9888A823BF2")
```

**This code does not return results:**

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", "level_id", String(levelId))
```

When debugging, printing out levelId returns the correct string from the first example: `"A2768F75-2293-4286-9ERA-D9888A823BF2"`

Thanks for the ideas and assistance!

Comment: The real difference here is in "=" and "==" in your predicates.

Comment: @Avt: That makes *no difference* in a NSPredicate.

Comment: `print(predicate)` could give a hint ...

Answer (score 2):

What type is levelId? Swift's string interpolation looks at items that implement the Printable protocol. So your type may have a String property `description` or `debugDescription`, in which case casting to a String won't give you what you want.

I'd try a test where compare the two values. For example, does `"A2768F75-2293-4286-9ERA-D9888A823BF2" == String(levelId)`? What about `levelId.description`?

Answer (score 1):

**=, ==**

> The left-hand expression is equal to the right-hand expression.

but the `==` to make it case-insensitive

if so , most of describe it, no difference `=` and `==` in predicates

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", "level_id", levelId as! String)
```

Comment: Sorry don't understand, why did you give my answer as negative? @Martin R